# Java Play - Binding a List of objects with a Map<String, AnotherObject> inside

Tags: java, data-binding, playframework

I am using Java Play framework 2.6. I am trying to present a list of objects (in this case chapters). Each chapter object contains inside a Map field. To illustrate this in a simple way:

```
public class ListChapters {
    private List<Chapter> formChapters;

    public List<Chapter> getFormChapters() {
        return formChapters;
    }

    public ListChapters setFormChapters(List<Chapter> formChapters) {
        this.formChapters = formChapters;
        return this;
    }
}  

public class Chapter {
    private String name;

    private Map<String, Material> materials;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Chapter setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Map<String, Material> getMaterials() {
        return materials;
    }

    public Chapter setMaterials(Map<String, Material> materials) {
        this.materials = materials;
        return this;
    }
}

public class Material {
    private String code;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public Material setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
        return this;
    }
}
```

In the template, I am populating the input boxes with some values (one row for each chapter and one row for each material field in the Map):

```
@repeatWithIndex(formChapters("formChapters"), min=chapters.size() ) { (field, index) =>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="@{field.name}.name" value="@chapters.get(index).getName()">@chapters.get(index).getName()</td>
    </tr>
    @for((key, material) <- chapters.get(index).getMaterials()){
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="@{field.name}.materials.@{material.getCode()}.code" value="@material.getCode()">@material.getCode()</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

chapters & formChapters are passed as parameters to the template:

> chapters: List[Chapter],  formChapters: Form[ListChapters]

Now - I am struggling for quite some time to figure it out how can I bind the form upon submit, to get the proper values.

The code to bind the request is pretty simple:

```
Form<ListChapters> chaptersForm = formFactory.form(ListChapters.class).bindFromRequest();
List<Chapter> formChapters = chaptersForm.get().getFormChapters();
```

The problem is that formChapters correctly binds the names of the chapters - but when it comes to materials - they all come empty.
Inspecting with Chrome, the form data is sent as follows:

```
formChapters[0].name: Some name
formChapters[0].materials.19931.code: 19931
formChapters[1].name: Some other name
formChapters[1].materials.6311231.code: 6311231
...
```

Isn't this the proper way to form the input name, so the binding get's done? Or what could be the problem?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play framework form request binding always assumes that collection keys (List, Map) will be provided in square brackets.

Form data should be send as follows:

```
formChapters[0].name: Some name
formChapters[0].materials[19931].code: 19931
formChapters[1].name: Some other name
formChapters[1].materials[6311231].code: 6311231
...
```